# Saving a rendered image with a transparent background thanks to a Python script in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, blender

In my Blender script, I want to save a rendered image with `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`. This rendered image is supposed to have a transparent background I try to set with `scene.render.film_transparent=True`, but it's desesperately black...

Any idea about what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works much better when color mode is set to "RGBA" instead of "RGB"...